# datahike clojurescript branch cljs-206 broken - how to run datahike with clojurescript?

Tags: database, clojurescript, datalog

- seems groundedSAGE has rewritten history
- none of the commits in his forks exist

  - https://github.com/replikativ/datahike/blob/90891e21cdfde6386861602d9f8231a3307da77d/deps.edn

how to run datahike right now with clojurescript?

Answer (score 0):

- we ended up copying - by downloading zip files of those ghost commits-  all the code from groundedSAGE's leftover logs
- and assembled the database to run on nodejs - Arthur-Dent - he works, just made transactions
- his source - datahike on nodejs - https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Arthur-Dent/tree/bd75f8b4f03a1471e7d326ce9b7b8d074205bae5
- program Fennec runs him now - https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Fennec/tree/f49352f7e8e58ab2804343d76fbf2913f02e2457

  - deps.edn where Arthur-Dent is imported
  - main.cljs where indexeddbshim is set up
  - beans.cljs for db creating and transaction and query

the namespace move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard - will be removed eventually
but - Arthur-Dent and Fennec and commits - will be there
so search by name not namespace

WRONG

solution

- commits still exist on github - in reflog
- solution is to fork, clone, checkout and push as new branch
- then using :exclusions in deps.edn replace groundedSAGEs git/urls with fork's